# How to loop over 2 dataframes or (lists) and replace every value with a label in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

###### My first variable called data

```
index <- seq(1:15)
name <- c('USA', "UK", "Canada", "Mexico", "Japan", "Brazil", "France", "Portugal", "Spain",
      "Argentina", "Qatar", "Dubai", "Malaysia", "Indonésia", "Signapour")
data <- cbind(index, name)
```

###### My second variable called df:

```
 var_1 <- 5 ;var_2 <- 3 ;var_3 <- 2 ;var_4 <- 9
 var_5 <- 1 ; var_6 <- 6 ; var_7 <- 7 ; var_8 <- 8 ; var_9 <- 4
 var_10 <- 15 ; var_11 <- 14 ; var_12 <- 12 ; var_13 <- 13
var_14 <- 11 ; var_15 <- 10

df <- cbind.data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9, var_10, 
 var_11, var_12, var_13, var_14, var_15)

df
```

###### I want to create a loop using for() and if(), to replace every value in df for each variable with column "name" in data

Comment: Please format the code to your second df correctly

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
data = as.data.frame(unlist(data))
df[1,]= data$name
```

Comment: Yes, but in my real data, my data frames have differents lenghts and the values are not classified